# How to calculate two columns data with conditions in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Date        Quantity Transaction_Type 
11-07-2017   200       Sale
15-07-2017   200       Purchase
20-07-2017   500       Sale
10-08-2017   200       Purchase
10-10-2017   200       Purchase
12-10-2017   200       Sale
12-12-2017   200       Sale
20-12-2017   500       Sale
```

How can i get the below output.

```
Month  Quantity
07      500
10      0
12      700
```

Comment: Please explain what you want. Review your output first.

Comment: I Want month wise only sales count which is remaining after sale-purchase

Comment: check the answer given by Gordon

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want:

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
       sum(case transaction_type when 'Purchase' then quantity
                                 when 'Sale' then - quantity
           end)
from t
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Note that I included the year in the month column.  If you don't want the year, remove it from the `to_char()` format.